# Insufficient privileges when adding FK constraint (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys

```
ALTER TABLE LAB_ADMIN_USER.TEST_TEMPLATE_ABBR ADD (
   CONSTRAINT TEST_TEMPLATE_ABBR_R01 
FOREIGN KEY (test_template_id) 
REFERENCES LAB_ADMIN.TEST_TEMPLATE (test_template_id)
   ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

What is the most likely cause of 'ORA=01031: insufficient privileges' when executing the command above?  In other words, what permission does LAB_ADMIN_USER most likely not have?

I already created the table successfully and attempted to add the FK constraint as LAB_ADMIN_USER.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The table with the primary key is owned by a different schema - LAB_ADMIN.  That user must grant REFERENCES on TEST_TEMPLATE to LAB_ADMIN_USER.

Answer (score 6):

From the owning schema execute `GRANT REFERENCES ON OWNINGSCHEMA.TABLE TO OTHERSCHEMA;`