# Oracle table or view does not exist when creating FK to other user

Tags: oracle

I have 3 users,  A, B C.  A is a dba. I login to sqlDeveloper with user A.

I create user B,  and add a table  "B"."USERS";

I create user C,  and add a table  "C"."SESSIONS";

those are all fine.

I then try to add a FK like this:

alter table "C"."SESSIONS" add constraint "FK_SESSIONS" foreign key ("LOCKEDBYUSERTOKEN_ID") references "B"."USERS" ("ID")

and I get a "table or view does not exist" error.

I thought that if user A was a dba,  that it could create views and constraints across users and schemas. What do I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Even though user A has DBA permissions, when you create a constraint on table C.SESSIONS, it attempts to read B.USERS as user C. You need to grant select privileges on B.USERS to user C.

Answer (score 0):

base on this link [Insufficient privileges when adding FK constraint (Oracle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262801/insufficient-privileges-when-adding-fk-constraint-oracle) ,you need to add foreign key constraint to users. for more information can refer to this link:
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:60443882718790